# Error when patching particular users to sharepoint person column from powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps-formula

I have a combobox that patches to a person column. However, there are some users whose details do not patch. It gives a network error message that says *"The specified user i:0#.f|membership| could not be found."*. I don't have this issue with the majority of users. I've tried everything I can think of... What could the problem be?

````
Set(varCurrentAdminRecord,
Patch(
    Units,
    varCurrentAdminRecord,
    {
        Unit: txt_AdminUnits_Unit1_1.Text,
        Department: txt_AdminUnits_Dept1_1.Text,
        UnitHead: {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(LookUp(Office365Users.SearchUserV2().value,DisplayName = cmb_AdminUnits_UnitHead1_1.Selected.DisplayName).Mail),
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: cmb_AdminUnits_UnitHead1_1.Selected.DisplayName,
            Email: cmb_AdminUnits_UnitHead1_1.Selected.Mail,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""
        },
        DepartmentHead: {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(LookUp(Office365Users.SearchUserV2().value,DisplayName = cmb_AdminUnits_DeptHead1_2.Selected.DisplayName).Mail),
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: cmb_AdminUnits_DeptHead1_2.Selected.DisplayName,
            Email: cmb_AdminUnits_DeptHead1_2.Selected.Mail,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""
        },
        Members:ForAll(
            cmb_AdminUnits_PayRequester_1.SelectedItems As _Sel,
            {
                '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
                Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(LookUp(Office365Users.SearchUserV2().value,DisplayName = _Sel.DisplayName).Mail),
                Department: "",
                DisplayName: _Sel.DisplayName,
                Email: _Sel.Mail,
                JobTitle: "",
                Picture: ""
            }
        )
    }
));

// check for errors
If(
    IsEmpty(Errors(Units)),
    // on success
    UpdateContext({locAdminFormDisplayMode: "View"});
    Notify(
        "Success: Record Saved",
        NotificationType.Success
    ),
    // on failure
    Notify(
        Concat(Errors(Units), Column&": "&Message),
        NotificationType.Error
    )
);
Refresh(Units)```
````